# Font not showing in libreoffice (6.0)

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and installed a ttf font (Didact Gothic) via the font manager.

However, this font isn't showing in libreoffice 6.0.

I allready tried rebooting program and pc, uninstalling and reïnstalling the font

Does anyone have a solution for this?

PS: It worked just fine on Ubuntu 16.04.
PPS: It does work in libreoffice Calc 6.0, but not in writer 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

It's a "snap" issue - if you use the "snap" version of Ubuntu, you will *not* be able to "see" any fonts you have installed in Ubuntu.

Close LibreOffice, if it is open.

Open Terminal - hold "Ctrl", "Alt" and press "T" - then enter:

```
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

Change your "working" directory - that is, where you *are* in Terminal - to that of LibreOffice:

```
cd ~/snap/libreoffice/current
```

Create a symbolic link ("shortcut") to your font folder:

```
ln -s /home/your-ubuntu-username/.local/share/fonts
```

Then run this command:

```
ln -s ~/.fonts .fonts
```

This *should* work (it did for me just then!) and I've tried to make it as easy to follow as possible - but you don't feel comfortable using Terminal commands, you can always switch to the "regular" version of LibreOffice...

Open Ubuntu Software and search for "libreoffice" - remove the one that has references to "snap" or "snapcraft.io" when you click on it (i.e. on the page that has the picture, description, etc...) - it *should* have these references under the "Details" section towards the bottom.

Hit the "back" arrow and install the "regular" version of the LibreOffice programs you need to use - these should *not* contain *any* references to "snap" or "snapcraft.io" under the "Details" section at the bottom.